# how can Rollout a page in cq through java class?

Tags: aem

I have website in multiple country . I rollout the content through MSM.

I want, if there is any page created and content approver , approves the page, then rollout should happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think is to set up a workflow, in which you can add review/approval steps and in case everything went well you can call a service for rolling out the page. As the previous comment mentioned the RolloutManager can be used for this. If you use msm you will probably also need to use the com.day.cq.wcm.msm.api.LiveRelationshipManager to achieve the live relations of a given page.